# Private Swift and ObjC dependencies inside framework

Tags: swift, objective-c, cocoa, clang, interop

In framework we are using Swift and Objective-C, so that Swift instances are instantiated within Objective-C methods. To be able to do so, we had to make those Swift files `public`/`open`, so they appear in `SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER` (`OurModule-Swift.h`), which is then imported by Objective-C. The problem is that we'd like to hide those Swift classes from public interface of framework. Apple says:

> For framework targets, only declarations with the `public` or `open` modifier appear in the generated header. You can still use Swift methods and properties that are marked with the `internal` modifier from within the Objective-C part of your framework, as long they are declared within a class that inherits from an Objective-C class. For more information on access-level modifiers, see Access Control in The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1).

So in theory it should be possible to have internal Swift classes created from Objective-C, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you quoted mentions only internal methods and properties, not classes.  The same documentation also says, in a different section:

> Swift methods and properties that are marked with the internal
>   modifier and declared within a class that inherits from an Objective-C
>   class are accessible to the Objective-C runtime. However, they are not
>   accessible at compile time and do not appear in the generated header
>   for a framework target.

See Importing Swift into Objective-C at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122

Thus you can make Swift classes `public`, so they are usable in the Objective-C part of your framework, but keep methods and properties of those classes `internal`.  Since they are not available at compile time, you can let the Objective-C code know about them by using class extensions a.k.a anonymous categories.

Suppose you have the following Swift class whose implementation you want to hide:

```
public class SecretSwiftClass : NSObject {    
    func swiftFun(arg1 a : Int32, arg2 b : Int32) -> Int32 {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

In your framework's Objective-C code you might use the internal `swiftFun()` method as follows:

```
#import "YourProduct-Swift.h"

// Use an extension to let the compiler know about the hidden method
@interface SecretSwiftClass ()
-(int32_t)swiftFunWithArg1:(int32_t)l arg2:(int32_t)m;
@end

// You will make this one visible to client code via the
// framework's umbrella header
@implementation PublicOCClass : NSObject

-(int32_t) ocFun:(int32_t)int1 :(int32_t)int2 {
    SecretSwiftClass * sc = [[SecretSwiftClass alloc] init];
    return [sc swiftFunWithArg1:int1 arg2: int2];
}

@end
```

Comment: I guess it works but it seems like hard to maintain and lot of manual work. Quite same as https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/ExportingInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002260-97049 where you can limit your API but still generating/writing exports file from hand doesn't seem to be the best thing to do.

Comment: Has anyone found a  tool that would generate these boilerplate interfaces?